# How to design table for dynamically in php with 3 rows after td and data

Tags: php

I have small problem for create a dynamic table from database. Given below image like design will came but not came for my code.

My code is

```
<tbody style="text-align:center;">
                       <tr style="background-color: #00335f; border-style: solid;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6><span style="color: #ffffff;">S.NO.</span></h6>
                          </td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6><span style="color: #ffffff;">CODE</span></h6>
                          </td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6 style="color: #ffffff;text-align:center;">SUBJECT NAME</h6>
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                                <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">COMPULSORY SUBJECTS</td>
                             </tr>
                       <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `bschool_semister` where bschool_semister_title = 'SEMESTER 3'";
                          $result = $conn->query($sql);
                          $count=$result->num_rows;
                          $i=1; 
                          while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 

                             $semcode= $row->bschool_semister_code;
                             $semname = $row->bschool_semister_name;  ?>
                       <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00335f;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$i;?></td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$semcode;?></td>
                          <td style="text-align:center;"> <?=$semname;?> </td>
                       </tr>
                        <?php $i++;
                           } ?>

                          <?php if( $i% 3 == 1)
                          { ?>
                              <tr>
                             <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">Specialization - Group (A): MARKETING</td>
                           </tr>
                          <?php $count++;
                           }  
                          while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 

                             $semcode= $row->bschool_semister_code;
                             $semname = $row->bschool_semister_name;  ?>
                       <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00335f;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$i;?></td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$semcode;?></td>
                          <td style="text-align:center;"> <?=$semname;?> </td>
                       </tr>

                       <?php $i++; }  ?>

                    </tbody>
```

But my out put look like this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTrM5.jpg)

Comment: Tony, Try to break this question into two problems. Problem 1: With plain HTML are you able to format mocked up data the way you want? Problem 2: Are you able to populate that HTML table with data from PHP? It's not clear where your problem is right now.

Comment: update if condtion `if($i == 3) { $i=0; ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
              <h4 style="margin-left:65px;">SEMESTER 3
              <br>(Each student has to take 3 compulsory courses + 1 project report and viva-voce + 2 courses from respective specialization)</h4>
              <div class="container pb-30fix mt-10 " >
                 <table class=" aligncenter" style="height: 265px; width: 90%; border-color: #00335f; font-weight:400px; margin-left:50px;" width="90%">
                    <tbody style="text-align:center;">
                       <tr style="background-color: #00335f; border-style: solid;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6><span style="color: #ffffff;">S.NO.</span></h6>
                          </td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6><span style="color: #ffffff;">CODE</span></h6>
                          </td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
                             <h6 style="color: #ffffff;text-align:center;">SUBJECT NAME</h6>
                          </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>COMPULSORY SUBJECTS</td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM `bschool_semister` where bschool_semister_title = 'SEMESTER 3' and 
                          `bschool_semister_category` = 'MBA' ";
                          $result = $conn->query($sql);
                          $count=$result->num_rows;
                          $i=1; 
                          while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                          $semcode= $row->bschool_semister_code;
                          $semname = $row->bschool_semister_name; 
                          $pdf = $row->bschool_semister_content; ?>
                       <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00335f;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$i;?></td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$semcode;?></td>
                          <td style="text-align:center;"> <a href="images/course/<?=rawurlencode($pdf);?>" target="_blank"> <?=$semname;?> </a></td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php
                          if($i == 3 ){ ?> 
                       <tr>
                          <td>Specialization - Group (A): MARKETING</td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php }
                          if($i == 5 ){ ?> 
                       <tr>
                          <td>Specialization - Group (B): FINANCE</td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php } if($i == 7 ){ ?> 
                       <tr>
                          <td>Specialization - Group (C): HUMAN RESOURCE</td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php }if($i == 9 ){ ?> 
                       <tr>
                          <td>Specialization - Group (D): SYSTEM</td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php }if($i == 11 ){ ?> 
                       <tr>
                          <td>COMPULSORY SUBJECT</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00335f;">
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">12</td>
                          <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> MBA 11312</td>
                          <td style="text-align:center;"> Project Report & Viva </td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php }
                          $i++; } ?> 
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: hi thank u  i will searching long back ago thank u update

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code:

**Issue:**

- By calling `while loop` twice in code increase page load time.
- The increment of `i` was initialized before the condition.

```html
<tbody style="text-align:center;">
    <tr style="background-color: #00335f; border-style: solid;">
    <td style="border-right: solid 1px #fff;">
      <h6><span>S.NO.</span></h6>
        </td>
          <td>
           <h6><span>CODE</span></h6>
                          </td>
                          <td >
                        <h6 style="color: #ffffff;text-align:center;">SUBJECT NAME</h6>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
     <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">COMPULSORY SUBJECTS</td>
    </tr>
     <?php 
     $sql="SELECT * FROM bschool_semister where bschool_semister_title = 'SEMESTER 3'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     $count=$result->num_rows;
      $i=1; 
      while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { 

         $semcode= $row->bschool_semister_code;
         $semname = $row->bschool_semister_name;  ?>
         <tr style="border-style: solid; border-color: #00335f;">
            <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$i;?></td>
            <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;"> <?=$semcode;?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"> <?=$semname;?> </td>
         </tr>
    <?php
      if($i == 3 ){ 
       $i=0;
      ?> 
          <tr>
         <td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">Specialization - Group (A): MARKETING</td>
       </tr>
       } $i++ } ?> 
  </tbody>
```

Comment: your code working for me for each itrate 3 rows but my problem is 1 row only 3 rows remain all two rows that to no change the serial number plz once check my image also

Comment: Then remove `$i=0;` from `loop` after `if($i == 3 ){`

Comment: or you need to make dynamic `<td style="border-right: solid 1px #00335f;">Specialization - Group (A): MARKETING</td>` according to categories

Comment: can u see the image sir first 3 another time 2 and Specialization also changed

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTrM5.jpg  once open the link see that image like output

Comment: @TonyNagendraKumar I did see your screenshot. But we can give a solution to solve the problem. and soltuion is here. How you can manupulate that soltion. it is up to you :)

Comment: @TonyNagendraKumar for  `serial number` assume a new `variable eg: $j=1`